# Receive at Watching Only Wallet

Tags: armory, coldstorage, watch-only

I am a little foggy about the Watching Wallet copy in Armory. I have received BTC in my Watching only wallet. Is there anything that I need to do now to get those to the Cold Storage Wallet or is the Cold storage Wallet only needed to sign Spending transactions.  If so then in that Case I assume that the accurate balance in the Cold Wallet does not need to be reflected as it is only used for spending?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to do anything.

> If so then in that Case I assume that the accurate balance in the Cold Wallet does not need to be reflected as it is only used for spending?

Correct. Without a means to gain knowledge about received money, the cold storage wallet can't update its balance. But it holds the private keys required to spend the money it received. The watch-only wallet can be used to check the balance without it having the ability to spend any money.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I was beginning to think that noone would after 11 views.